# ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled - Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

[Here's the link for the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXO9d.png)

Public Class frmMenu

```
Private Sub UserMaintenanceToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UserMaintenanceToolStripMenuItem.Click
    frmUser.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Me.StatusStrip1.Items(0).Text = strUser
    Me.StatusStrip1.Items(1).Text = Today()
    Me.StatusStrip1.Items(2).Text = TimeOfDay()
End Sub
```

End Class

After I log in an existing user the error appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Items array of the StatusStrip1 element has no items. You need to make sure to fill it before you try to acces it.